# Acra can't send a report

Tags: android, acra

I've configured a acra storage database on couchappy.com.
    acra-storage: http://[myapp].couchappy.com/acra-[myapp]

On my acralyzer app, I've created a cespa-reporter user.

```
@ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "",
        formUri = "http://[myapp].couchappy.com/acra-[myapp]/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
        reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
        formUriBasicAuthLogin = "cespa-reporter",
        formUriBasicAuthPassword = "xxxxxxx",
        customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME, ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT }
        )
public class CespaApp extends Application {
```

When acra is trying to send a crash report tells me almost nothing:

```
02-05 14:31:20.632: W/dalvikvm(15882): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5b438)
02-05 14:31:20.632: E/ACRA(15882): ACRA caught a NullPointerException exception for com.gmsoft. Building report.
02-05 14:31:20.642: D/ACRA(15882): Using custom Report Fields
02-05 14:31:20.662: I/ACRA(15882): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
02-05 14:31:20.692: D/ACRA(15882): Retrieving logcat output...
02-05 14:31:20.732: D/ACRA(15882): Writing crash report file 1391610680000.stacktrace.
02-05 14:31:20.742: D/ACRA(15882): About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
02-05 14:31:20.742: D/ACRA(15882): Mark all pending reports as approved.
02-05 14:31:20.742: D/ACRA(15882): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.gmsoft/files
02-05 14:31:20.742: D/ACRA(15882): #checkAndSendReports - start
02-05 14:31:20.742: D/ACRA(15882): Looking for error files in /data/data/com.gmsoft/files
02-05 14:31:20.742: I/ACRA(15882): Sending file 1391609009000-approved.stacktrace
02-05 14:31:20.752: D/ACRA(15882): Waiting for Toast + worker...
02-05 14:31:20.762: D/ACRA(15882): Connect to http://cespacra.couchappy.com/acra-cespapp/_design/acra-storage/_update/report
02-05 14:31:20.772: D/ACRA(15882): Sending request to http://cespacra.couchappy.com/acra-cespapp/_design/acra-storage/_update/report/null
```

As you can see only tells me that is trying to send the report, but nothing more.
I'd like to know why acra isn't abled to send the report.

Could you help me, please?